# How to access Azure Key Vault with Network Security Policy enables?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have **2** Deployments are as follow:

1. **Orient DB Deployment.**
2. **Web Service Deployment.**

Initially, To access Orient DB, Web service fetch the Orient DB username and password which are stored in **Azure Key Vault**.

To provide extra security, I created a network security policy which only allows pods with **namespaceSelector "application: production"** and **podSelector "application: production"**.
The network security policy applied are as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: nmsp
  namespace: production
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      application: production
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          application: production
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          application: production
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          application: production
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          application: production
```

But, after applying network security policy the Web service is unable to connect with Orient DB because Web service is failed to get username and password from **Azure key vault**.
It gives error,

```
Unhandled Rejection at: FetchError: request to https://in-keyvault-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets?api-version=7.1 failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN in-aks-keyvault-kv.vault.azure.net
at ClientRequest. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:428:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
code: 'EAI_AGAIN'
}
```

**SO how can I access this key vault for the username and password with network security policy enables? and  connect with orient DB service?**

If any one know please help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add an egress rule that enable the port 443 (And IP Range of the Key Vault service if you want to restrict the traffic) or use a something like [Azure Key Vault provider for Secret Store CSI driver](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure) to get secret contents stored in Azure Key Vault instance and use the Secret Store CSI driver interface to mount them into Kubernetes pods.